# LINQ - Return a List within a List

Tags: c#, linq

I have imported my database into my EF Model,and I'm trying to create a linq query which returns the appropriate ViewModel.

The table *Items* reflects *ItemDetailVM* class

The table *Property* reflects *PropertyVM* class

There is a navigation property between *Items* and *Property*

The linq query im trying to write is below...

My question is how do I map the *prop* within *ItemDetailVM*?

```
var query = (from items in DbContext.Items
         select new ItemDetailVM
         {
            item1 = items.id,
            item2 = items.value,
            //prop = CODE HERE... select new PropertyVM{ ....}
         }).ToList();


class ItemDetailVM
{
    string item1;
    string item2;
    List<Property> prop;
}

class PropertyVM
{
    string prop1;
    string prop2;
    string prop3;
}
```

Comment: Does each property have a reference to an item or do you want the full list of properties in each item?

Comment: looks like you want to `eagerly load` the list ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186009/linq-to-entities-eager-loading-using-include

Comment: I do not want the full list of properties, but a subset. The eager load would load all properties

Comment: What condition do you want to apply to filter the properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = (from items in DbContext.Items
             select new ItemDetailVM
             {
               item1 = items.id,
               item2 = items.value,
               prop = items.prop.Select(p=>new PropertyVM{prop1=p.prop1,
                                                          prop2=p.prop2, 
                                                          prop3=p.prop3}).ToList()
             }).ToList();
```

If you have disabled lazy loading, then you need to call the `Include` extension method:

```
var query = (from items in DbContext.Items.Include(i=>i.prop)
             select new ItemDetailVM
             {
               item1 = items.id,
               item2 = items.value,
               prop = items.prop.Select(p=>new PropertyVM{prop1=p.prop1,
                                                          prop2=p.prop2, 
                                                          prop3=p.prop3}).ToList()
             }).ToList();
```