# Multiple select query in linq c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following classes.

```
public class Candidate
{
    public long Id { get; set; )
    public List<JobAssigned> JobAssigned { get; set; }       
}

public class JobAssigned
{
    public long Id { get; set; }     
    public List<StageScore> StageScore { get; set; }
    public List<CriteriaScore> CriteriaScore { get; set; }
    public List<StageComment> StageComment { get; set; }       
}

public class StageComment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public JobAssigned  JobAssigned { get; set; }
    public long JobAssignedId { get; set; }
    public long PipelineStageId { get; set; }
    public long CandidateId { get; set; }
    public long JobId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class StageScore
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public JobAssigned JobAssigned { get; set; }
    public long JobAssignedId { get; set; }
    public long Rating { get; set; }
    public long PipelineStageId { get; set; }
    public long CandidateId { get; set; }
    public long JobId { get; set; }
}

public class CriteriaScore
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public JobAssigned JobAssigned { get; set; }
    public long JobAssignedId { get; set; }
    public long Rating { get; set; }
    public long PipelineStageCriteriaId { get; set; }
    public long CandidateId { get; set; }
    public long JobId { get; set; }
}
```

I want eager load all the related table at once. I was trying to the followning,

```
List<Candidate> candidate = _context.Candidates.                
          Include(f => f.JobAssigned.Select(g => g.StageScore))
          .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

When I did `.Select().Select()` it was giving an error. How to get all the collections in a single query?

Comment: Look at Include...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186009/linq-to-entities-eager-loading-using-include

Comment: "it was giving an error" What did the error tell you?

Comment: List<Candidate> candidate = _context.Candidates.                
          Include(f => f.JobAssigned.Select(g => g.StageScore).Select(h => h.StageComment)).
          .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();   I was trying to  do that, but for 2nd Select() there were no suggestions.

Comment: try `ThenInclude` as given [here](https://entityframework-classic.net/then-include)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1205294/Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Include-Hierarchy.) I wrote, it loads all the objects dynamically.

And here is how you could include all objects.

I hope that there won't be circle references.

The plugin I wrote in the above url can handle circle references

```
List<Candidate> candidate = _context.Candidates.                
    Include(f => f.JobAssigned.Select(g => g.StageScore.Select(a=> a.JobAssigned))).
    Include(f => f.JobAssigned.Select(g => g.CriteriaScore.Select(a=> a.JobAssigned))).
    Include(f => f.JobAssigned.Select(g => g.StageComment.Select(a=> a.JobAssigned))).
    OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: I think it also will work like the following:

List<Candidate> candidate = _context.Candidates.                
          Include(f => f.JobAssigned.Select(a => a.StageScore)).
Include(g => h.JobAssigned.Select(b => b.StageComment)).
Include(h => h.JobAssigned.Select(c => c.CriteriaScore))
          .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();

Comment: well you could test it :)