# Related objects are not loaded in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 POCO classes like Category and Parent. In my conceptual model, I have a navigation property from Parent to Category, but not the other way around (from Category to Product).

I have been able to successfully create a Product and assign a Category to it and save the changes, like:

```
Product p = new Product();
p.Category = someCategory; 
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, when I load Products, Category is property NULL. Any advice?

Cheers,
Mosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *eager loading* the **Category** when you retrieve the **Product**:

```
var product = ctx.Products.Single(x => x.ProductId == 1).Include("Category");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to RPM's answer, I asked a related question a while ago on getting compile-time checking for the stuff you Include():

[Entity Framework .Include() with compile time checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921119/entity-framework-include-with-compile-time-checking)