# Reduce massive includes in EF

Tags: entity-framework, include

Any ways to shorten this include statement?

```
var query = Context.Businesses
 .Include(b => b.Categories)
 .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.Address))
 .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.BranchType))
 .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.CustomFields))
 .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.Phones))
 .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.OpeningTimes.Select(ot => ot.WorkingPeriods)));
```

I thought about using a SPROC but I'm unsure how it will know what was returned.

So is there a non hard-coded way to do this shorter than it is? Perhaps an external lambda that treats all the properties of `Branch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities). So in your case, make an extension method like this:

```
public static class DataContextExtensions
{
   public static IQueryable<Business> BusinessesComplete(this DataContext context){
         return context.Businesses
             .Include(b => b.Categories)
             .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.Address))
             .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.BranchType))
             .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.CustomFields))
             .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.Phones))
             .Include(b => b.Branches.Select(br => br.OpeningTimes.Select(ot => ot.WorkingPeriods)));
     }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
Business business = context.BusinessesComplete().Where(b => ...etc);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do compile this function so the generated SQL doesn't have to be calculated each time again?

Comment: In EF 5 this is availeble for LINQ queries and enabled by default, not sure if you can enable it in earlier versions though. Worth reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx