# How to get Country Name based on its Id in Entity framework using Mvc?You can just have a look at the following things

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

[image: This is my database]

The above is my database .I have for tables Contact,Countries,States,Cities.The Country in contact table is foreign key to the Id in countries table. And I am using entity framework to get the data.I am using database first   approach.I am getting my Contact details by the following code

```
public class ContactManager
    {
        public static List<Contact> GetContacts()
        {
            using (var obj = new EntityDBConnectionString())
            {
                return obj.Contacts.ToList();
            }
        }
}
```

And in the Controller part I have like this

```
public ActionResult ViewContacts()
        {

            return View("ViewContacts",ContactManager.GetContacts());
        }
```

and atlast the View(cshtml)

```
@model  List<Entity.Data.Contact>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewContacts";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>ViewContacts</h2>
<table style="font-family:'Segoe UI';font-size:20px;display:table" border="1" cell-spacing="1" >

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
             <tr style="border:1px solid black;padding-right:3px;background-color:lightblue;display:table-row">
    <td>@item.Id</td>
    <td>@item.Name</td>
    <td>@item.Mobile</td>
    <td>@item.EmailId</td>   
    <td>@item.Address</td>
    <td>@item.Country</td>
</tr>
        }

</table>
```

My problem is that I am getting the CountryId's in the output table as it is a foreign.Can I get the Country Name as output

The output I am getting is the below one

[image: Output]

How to get the Country name in the data part and pass to the controller and how to pass it to the view? Can anyone help me out .Thanks in advance!!!!!!

The below is my Contact class

```
public partial class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> City { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> State { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Country { get; set; }

        public virtual City City1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country1 { get; set; }
        public virtual State State1 { get; set; }
    }
```

and the edmx file is[image]

Comment: If you have the relationship setup correctly at the DB end EF is clever enough to generate a navigation property for you so you shouldn't even need to query the table separately i.e. `contact.Country.Name`.

Answer (score 3):

I asume that you have set database realtionship for country and contact table. now in view you can get country name using

```
<td>@item.Country.Name</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please `Include` your `Country` table in EF query like to bring the country

```
 public static List<Contact> GetContacts()
    {
        using (var obj = new EntityDBConnectionString())
        {
            return obj.Contacts.Include("Country").ToList();
        }
    }
```

and use the below in your view

```
@item.Country.Name
```

Comment: To elaborate on this further, the `Include()` function loads the `Country` entity into the context, precluding the need to make a database call when calling `Contacts` navigation property.

Comment: I am getting this error Murali  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @BharatBhushan, please check whether your `model` or `item` have the `Country` object? If yes please check the hierarchy and place it in a view

Comment: @BharatBhushan does your Contact model has a `virtual` property for Country?

Comment: @BharatBhushan, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities for adding additional data

Comment: yeah its having a virtual property for Country ..But it is Country1. So is it going to be a problem.?

Comment: @BharatBhushan, what is the country property name in your contact class? use that one. Before use, check whether the EF is filling the Country in the query result

Comment: I have just edited the question you have a look at that Contact class.

Comment: @BharatBhushan, try with `@item.Country1.Name`. Are you able to fill the country in `obj.Contacts.Include("Country").ToList()`?

Comment: NO its saying that we dont have a navigation proprty with name "Country" its not getting filled.Do we need to use extension methods ?

Comment: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'EntityDBModel.Contact' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Country'.          This is the error

Comment: @BharatBhushan, try using `obj.Contacts.Include("Country1").ToList()`

Comment: @BharatBhushan [check this and try](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+EntityType++does+not+declare+a+navigation+property+with+the+name)

Comment: Is it becoz of lazy loading?