# Entity Framework: Load related objects/tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to save my data to a database. Now I have a class:

```
public class User 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }
   public virtual User BestFriend { get; set; }

   public User()
   {
      Friends = new HashSet<User>();
   }
}
```

I load a User with

```
User user;
using(var context = DatabaseContext) 
{
   user = context.Users.Select(x => x.Id == 1);
}
```

the `Friends` and `BestFriend` property is `null`. This however is working:

```
  User user;
  using(var context = DatabaseContext) 
  {
     user = context.Users.Include(x => x.BestFriend).Include(x => x.Friends).Select(x => x.Id == 1);
  }
```

This leaves me with the Problem that e.g. `user.BestFriend.BestFriend` is null. I could include this property, too, but this would lead only to more problem a level deeper.

How know that lazy-loading and eagerly loading does exists, but I don't know how to use any of this here to my advantage.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities and at this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: @EduardDumitru as this describes both methods good, it does not help me regarding how to avoid needing load many levels manually.

Comment: There is no magic way to do recursive querying with LINQ to a SQL backend. Nothing you can do about is. You can only allow lazy loading by extending the context's lifespan.

Comment: @GertArnold And it is  good thing too, that you have to specify the levels, otherwise you could end up pulling the entire table into memory. Go figure facebook for instancen :-)

Comment: @Dabblernl but can't I configure it, that it will reload it, if I access it. Like lazy loading but outside the context.

Comment: @Campl3r Well, you can always write code in the BestFriend Property's getter that checks if it is null. Or you can encapsulate the User entitiy in an other class.