# Access child of child, both with 1:M

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Trying to get child of child, both with many relationship.

So a CarePeriod has many DailyExerciseSets which has many ExerciseTrials.
so carePeriod has collection of DailyExerciseSets which has a collection of ExerciseTrials
SQL I would write is

```
SELECT <bla>
FROM careperiods 
 left outer JOIN DailyExerciseSets ON (...) 
 left outer JOIN exerciseTrials ON (...)
WHERE
 careperiods.bla = bla
 AND DailyExerciseSets.bla = bla
 AND exerciseTrials.bla = bla
```

Just need to replicate this logic in EF/LINQ.
I have worked around this issue a couple times but really want to see how this is meant to be accomplished.

intuitively i would have gone for

```
var x = (from cp in db.carePeriod
.include(cp => cp.DailyExerciseSets) //this bit is fine
.include(cp => cp.DailyExerciseSets.exerciseTrials) //fail...
where (conditions...)
select cp);
```

but this fails..

A point in the right direction would be great.

Comment: use the mentioned link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include collections you need to use a "sub select" and not the dot-notation:

```
var x = (from cp in db.carePeriod
             .Include(cp => cp.DailyExerciseSets)
             .Include(cp => cp.DailyExerciseSets.Select(es => es.exerciseTrials))
         where (conditions...)
         select cp);
```

Also you do not need `Include(cp => cp.DailyExerciseSets)` here, as this is already included by the "child include":

```
var x = (from cp in db.carePeriod
             .Include(cp => cp.DailyExerciseSets.Select(es => es.exerciseTrials))
         where (conditions...)
         select cp);
```

Comment: Thanks. works. one follow up, how would you go another level down? i.e if exerciseTrials had a collection of entities that you wanted to grab as well?

Comment: Never done that, but should work the same: `.Include(cp => cp.DailyExerciseSets.Select(es => es.exerciseTrials.Select(t => t.Sub)))`.

Comment: yeh thats what I tried after your answer, no luck.Thanks tho.