# Read object inside object in entity framework from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im making a movieshop for school. I have a movie as a domain model, and each of these models has another model, Genre, as a property. Now when i save this to the database, it adds the movie and the genre to each of their tables, and it matches creates a genre id for det for movie and matches it with the genre table.

The problem is, that when i read the movie from the db again, the genre is null. it doesnt even have the genre id.

How do i assign the genre from the db to the movie?

```
public void Add(Movie mov)
    {

        using (Context mCon = new Context())
        {
            mCon.Movies.Add(mov);
            mCon.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

this^ is where i add the movie.

```
public List<Movie> GetAllMovies()
    {
        using (Context mCon = new Context())
        {
            return mCon.Movies.ToList();
        }
    }
```

and this is where i read it back from the db

EDIT*

```
Movie movie = new Movie() { Id = 1, Name = "Movie1", Price = 200d, Genre = new Genre() { Id = 1, Name = "Genre1" } };
```

EDIT**
My context contains the dbset for genres and movies.

i add the movie i created to my facade:

```
facade.GetMovieRep().Add(movie);
```

Comment: How are you assigning the `Genre` to the `Movie`? please show that code? is there a Form involved, web, mobile, or desktop?

Comment: hi Jonas Olesen you have to do this , check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities  Its some normal your trouble on the structure your model, is for that you have to include the relations

Comment: @GlennFerrie I added the assignment at the bottom, and currently im only trying to it to work in a console app

Comment: @JonasOlesen and how do you add them to your context? Meaning do you add Genre?  Is a new Genre created for each movie?

Comment: Does your context contain a DbSet<Genres> property?

Comment: Is the Genre property set as virtual on the Movie class? This should help with Lazy Loading.

Comment: @GlennFerrie I currently create a new genre when i create the movie the genre is added to the db via the movie its tied to.

Comment: @DDiVita No it is not

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

I just added .include("Genre") when i return the context to list

Comment: If you want to use lazy loading you can set the properties for Genre as virtual. This tells EF to include them as part of the result.