# EagerLoad entity referenced by complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have an entity called Address. An Address contains a complex type, called House. A House contains a reference to its occupants. An Occupant is an entity.

```
public class Address {

    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public House House { get; set; }
}
```

The House:

```
[ComplexType] 
public class House
{

    [Required]
    public string HouseType { get; set; }


    public IList<Occupant> Occupants { get; set; }
}
```

The occupant

```
public class Occupant
{

    [key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

}
```

If I use lazyloading everything works fine and i can access all properties. However I need to use EagerLoading as the entities are needed long after the Context has been disposed.

I have tryed to include the properties using this code:

```
   // DbSet is of type DbSet<Address>
   List<Address> eagerLoadedEntity = DbSet.Where(a => a.Address.StartsWith("a"))
                .Include(a => a.House.Occupants).ToList();
```

I get the following error:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Address' does
>   not declare a navigation property with the name 'House'.

Comment: What type is `DbSet`? `DbSet<Address>`?

Comment: Oh.... wait..... you have an Address  class within the Address class....
Maybe you wanted a House there?

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou Yes I wanted house there.

Comment: Wait, what does your database actually look like? How did you manage to create that database?

Comment: The reason it works is because of a back reference from Occupant to Address. This is not an ideal scheme for the situation shown in this example, however it makes sense in the context. I made a workaround where the related entities are fetched using an extra query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is not possible at all?
[MSDN Complex Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680147.aspx)

> Complex types cannot participate in associations and cannot contain navigation properties.

You are treating "Occupants" as a navigation property on "House" on the "Include" statement and i suppose this might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible

check [SO link to how to do nested eagerLoading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities)

something like: This is just an example not tested... you will need to tweak.

```
   List<Address> eagerLoadedEntity = Context.Addresses
                         .Include("House")
                         .Include("House.Occupants")
                         .Where(a => a.Address.StartsWith("a"))
                         .ToList();
```

**Update**

Sorry i think you maybe correct about ComplexTypes.... but if they were all db entities then you should be able to do... something like... just an FYI

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int HouseId {get; set;}

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set;}

    public House House {get; set;}
}
public class House
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string HouseType {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Occupant> Occupants { get; set;}
}

public class Occupant
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int HouseId {get; set;}
    public int PersonId {get; set;}

    public bool IsOwner {get; set;}
    public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}

    public Person Person {get; set;}
    public House House {get; set;}
}

public class Person 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

eager load

```
List<Address> eagerLoadedEntity = Context.Addresses
                         .Include("House")
                         .Include("House.Occupants")
                         .Where(a => a.Address.AddressLine1.StartsWith("a"))
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Doing so will result in the same Error.

Comment: @Kabahango thanks you made me google ComplexType... I believe you maybe correct there... Thx