# Select multiple nested levels of child tables in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to get multiple nested levels of child tables in Entity Framework Core using eager loading. I don't think lazy loading is implemented yet.

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities) for EF6.

```
var company = context.Companies
                 .Include(co => co.Employees.Select(emp => emp.Employee_Car))
                 .Include(co => co.Employees.Select(emp => emp.Employee_Country))
                 .FirstOrDefault(co => co.companyID == companyID);
```

My problem is that `Select` is not recognized in EF Core

> Error  CS1061  'Employees' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Employees' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My included namespaces:

```
using MyProject.Models;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

What is the alternative for `Select` in EF Core.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use the keyword `ThenInclude` instead

e.g.

```
var company = context.Companies
             .Include(co => co.Employees).ThenInclude(emp => emp.Employee_Car)
             .Include(co => co.Employees).ThenInclude(emp => emp.Employee_Country)
             .FirstOrDefault(co => co.companyID == companyID);
```

Comment: Am I insane, or does this no longer work in EF Core 1.1.0? .ThenInclude treats the parent as an ICollection, offering me the collection properties instead of a single element's properties :/

Comment: @JasonX It is a bug in IntelliSense, just write you query as it would be an entity and it will work fine.

Comment: @DanielZolnai did you report the bug by any chance - or how did you find it? Do you have a link to the GitHub issue?

Comment: @cdavid It's listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels) in the docs, and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237) on github. Unrelated: Painful that I have to do the `.Include` twice for grandchildren from the same child (in your (firste's) case, `Employees`). But excellent example; thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Also, the .ThenInclude intellisense for only works up to the 3rd level, for example:

```
_Context.A.Include(a => a.B).ThenInclude(B => B.C).ThenInclude(C => C.D)
```

The last part of that statement:

```
 .ThenInclude(C => C.D)
```

won't show "D", so you have to type D in yourself, then wait for a short period of time for the compilation error to disappear!

Comment: Using dotnet 5 and EF Core, intellisense is working at 3rd and 4th level (and possibly beyond).

Comment: Nice.  About time!