# Using EF Core ThenInclude() on Junction tables

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm transfering my .NET Framework (EF6) code to ASP.NET Core (EF Core), and I stumbled upon this issue. Here is some example code:

In EF6 I use Include() and Select() for eager-loading:

```
return _context.Post
.Include(p => p.PostAuthor.Select(pa => pa.Author).Select(a => a.Interests))
```

PostAuthor is a junction table and there is also a Junction table "AuthorInterest" which I didn't need to involve in EF6 (Select goes straight to a.Interests).

Anyway, I can see that in EF7 this is reworked, meaning that I should use ThenInclude() for nested queries now. However...

```
return _context.Post
  .Include(p => p.PostAuthor)
    .ThenInclude(pa => pa.Select(pa2 => pa2.Author))
...etc
```

The above code fails because of the Select() statement. The documentation on https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html seems to suggest that I don't need it and I can access Author immediately, but I get an ICollection in the last lambda displayed, so I obviously need the Select(). I go through multiple junction tables further on in the query, but for simplicity's sake, let's just focus on the first one.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> but I get an ICollection in the last lambda displayed, so I obviously need the Select()

No, you don't. EF Core `Include` / `ThenInclude` totally replace the need of `Select` / `SelectMany` used in EF6. Both they have separate overloads for collection and reference type navigation properties. If you use the overload with collection, `ThenInclude` operates on the type of the collection **element**, so at the end you always end up with a single entity type.

In your case, `pa` should resolve to your junction table element type, so `Author` should be directly accessible.

For instance the EF6 include chain:

```
.Include(p => p.PostAuthor.Select(pa => pa.Author).Select(a => a.Interests))
```

translates to EF Core:

```
.Include(p => p.PostAuthor).ThenInclude(pa => pa.Author).ThenInclude(a => a.Interests)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Very weird - Visual studio would not give me intellisense for pa.Author (instead suggests some Linq methods) and would underline everything with red as soon as I try to write it.
After your post I disregarded VS and after compiling everything worked like a charm.

Comment: That's strange. I'm using VS2015 Update 3, and when I write something like `db.Parents.Include(p => p.Children).ThenInclude(c => c.Child).ThenInclude(c => c.Parents)` I get correct Intellisense support at each lambda.

Comment: VS2015 Ultimate Update 3 here, too. Not too surprised, I have other bugs on core projects - for example when I select an item suggested by intellisense it writes the symbols in the middle of the file, etc.

Maybe it's the plugins...

Comment: Good comparison.+1 :)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 Preview 2 and I get the same wrong intellisense. Just ignore that and build successfully :)

Comment: I am also having the IntelliSense issue in Visual Studio 2017 Pro, since there are a few others in the comments here having the issue I opened an issue on GitHub for the EF team: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/9374

Comment: The lack of intellisense is Roslyn issue. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237
If you are using 3rd party tool like R# then it extends intellisense to give you correct results.

Comment: Looks like this will be resolved in Roslyn in VS2019 Update 1, according to the linked ticket by @Smit.