# How to include a property from Collection with EntityFramework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this relationship :

```
public class Company
{
  public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Inside of Employee I have a Profile property:

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to get all the employees but not the `Profile` property.

And the request :

```
var result = await Context.Company.Include(a => a.Employee).Where(a => a.Token == Token).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The result is retrieved but not the Profile.

Comment: Try using the `ThenInclude` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-3.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using EF Core ThenInclude() on Junction tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319251/using-ef-core-theninclude-on-junction-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @jcruz pointed out ThenInclude in EF Core is what you want:

```
var result = await Context.Company.Include(a => a.Employee).ThenInclude(e => e.Profile).Where(a => a.Token == Token).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: I had found about the `ThenInclude` but it wasn't working, because the relationship from Profile to Employee one to one was made but in reverse, not is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Include()` function to the string overload and include the `Profile` property.

```
var result = await Context.Company.Include("Employee.Profile").Where(a => a.Token == Token).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```