# EF 6 load nested entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have nested entites like example from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

```
var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                   .Include(b => b.Posts.Select(p => p.Comments)) 
                   .ToList();
```

But in my case, Comment have structure like this:

```
public class Comment
{
    public List<User> ViewedUsers { get; set; };
}
```

How can i load ViewedUsers in this case, if method `.ThenInclude()` is unavalable? I mean new layer of nested entites.

Comment: you mean like `.Include(b => b.Posts.Select(p => p.Comments.Select(c => c.ViewedUsers)))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework linq query Include() multiple children entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities)

Comment: @grek40 Yes, like this. But this example dont work.

Comment: @ste-fu Not a duplicate, add additional layer of nested entites. If employee have new nested entity of Employee_Car in your example.

Comment: @flybox I just tried exactly as I commented and it is working for me. Be sure to test your code precisely the way you ask, because different things can screw the include (like `Include(...).Select(...)` will not work as expected).

Comment: @grek40 Use .Select not on p.Comments, use it after bracket like in my answer. It works.

Comment: @flybox wait a second... is `Post.Comments` not a collection?

Comment: @grek40 Collection, Comment is element of collection Comments.

Comment: @grek40 i was wrong, testing this on not a collection element. You are right.

Comment: @grek40 i changed answer and understood, what is wrong in my case. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case i need to use next statement:

```
var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
               .Include(b => b.Posts.Select(p => p.Comments.Select(cm => cm.ViewedUsers))) 
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Add another closing brace to code line 2 and you are done ;)