# Repository pattern issue with API controller querying of intermediate table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

Here is Repository, in which I created a methods in which I needed the data on the basis of intermediate table.

```
public Task<IEnumerable<DepartmentSchool>> GetAllDepartmentBySchoolIdAsync(int schoolId)
    {
        var school = _GpsContext.School.Where(e => e.ID == schoolId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (school == null)
            return NotFound();
        var departments = _GpsContext.DepartmentSchool
            .Where(e => e.SchoolsId == schoolId).Select(e => e.DepartmentID);
        return Ok(departments);

    }
```

And the method is called from my controller class to get value on the basis of the methods.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DepartmentSchoolController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IDepartmentSchoolRepository _departmentSchoolRepository;
    public DepartmentSchoolController(DepartmentSchoolRepository departmentSchoolRepository)
    {
        _departmentSchoolRepository = departmentSchoolRepository;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calling depatment on the basis of school id. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="schoolId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet("school/{schoolId}/departments")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DepartmentSchoolRepository>> GetDepartmentsFromSchool(int schoolId)
    {
        return await _departmentSchoolRepository.GetAllDepartmentBySchoolIdAsync();
    }
```

Can, please tell me where is the problem. Above code is not working and also showing problem in `NotFound()` and `Ok()` 'does not exist in the current context', what I have need to do?

Here is related entity:

```
public class DepartmentSchool
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public int SchoolsId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SchoolsId")]
    public virtual Schools Schools { get; set; }
}

public partial class Schools
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

}

public partial class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SchoolSystemsID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem/error ?

Comment: Above code is not working and also showing problem in  NotFound() and  Ok() 'does not exist in the current context', what I have need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a bunch of issues, including that it doesn't compile.

In your controller:

- You don't want to be returning repositories from your controller. Since you're using .net-core, why not use the `IActionResult` type as [per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#asynchronous-action)

```
[HttpGet("school/{schoolId}/departments")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDepartmentsFromSchool(int schoolId)
{
    var departments = await _departmentSchoolRepository
        .GetAllDepartmentBySchoolIdAsync(schoolId);
    if (departments.Any())
    {
        return Ok(departments)
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

In your repository:

- You're not awaiting either of your EF calls. As such, both these calls would return a `Task` instead of the EF Entity types that you are expecting.
- From the names of the methods, it seems you want to project out all departments from a given school. To do this, use the navigation properties you've defined in your EF model.
- You'll need to materialize the second query and change the return type (`.ToListAsync()`)
- You'll also need to mark the method as `async`
- Don't use HTTP / Web Api stuff like `Ok` / `NotFound` in a repository layer - this should be reserved for your controller layer.
- For your own sanity, in LINQ, use lambda variable names which represent the type that they represent. e.g. I've used `ds` below for `DepartmentSchool`, and `s` for `School`, below.

```
// ** Return type is the projected result
public async Task<IEnumerable<Department>> GetAllDepartmentBySchoolIdAsync(int schoolId) // ** async
{
    var school = await _GpsContext.School // ** await 
       .Where(s => s.ID == schoolId)
       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 
    if (school == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<Department>(); // Avoid returning nulls
    var departments = await _GpsContext.DepartmentSchool // ** await
        .Where(ds => ds.SchoolsId == schoolId)
        .SelectMany(ds => ds.Department) // ** flatten and project the navigation property
        .ToListAsync(); // ** materialize
    return departments; // ** Don't use Http stuff like OK in Repo layer
}
```

Note also that your first query is actually redundant. If you have referential integrity enforced in your database, it is impossible to have a `DepartmentSchool` junction row without a linked `School`, so you should be able to look just for the `DepartmentSchool` rows.

In the above, I've assumed that you've got lazy loading enabled. If you don't you'll need to eager load (i.e. join) the `DepartmentSchool -> Department` navigation as [per here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092178).