# Check if user exists and return user + roles EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to figure out how can i retrieve roles with Any and check if user exists on the same query and return as SingleOrDefault() but doesn't seem to work.

```
private User Authenticate(LoginViewModel model)
{
     using (HutLogisticaContext context = new HutLogisticaContext())
     {
         return context.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Contains(model.Username)).SingleOrDefault();
     }
}
```

However it won't let met add single or default if i add Any. How can i do both on same query?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention but I want to return the user object with all the roles related to it, not sure if it's possible without navigation property because i could not use include

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataSessao { get; set; }
    public bool IsActivo { get; set; }

    public virtual Colaborador Colaborador { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<App> Apps { get; set; }
}
```

i'm using EF 6 so this created automatically the join table with UserId and RoleId as PK and FK

Comment: Which role do you want to check with `Any`?

Comment: It's a many to many relation, so it should be returning every role where it matches the user ID, I saw this on an example, I mean, it shoudl return the user object with all the roles associated

Comment: So you want to retrun Role or User?

Comment: I want to return the user object with the roles, i'm not sure if this is possible without navigation property tho

Comment: And whats the filter criteria for this? either UserID or Username or any else

Comment: UserID since the join table only has UserID and RoleID

Comment: Do you have set PK, FK and is there navigation property available. Could you please post User and Role classes? and all relevant classes?

Comment: updated main post, you can check

Comment: As you said *I want to return the user object with the roles,* then you can try like this => `context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == 123).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: problem with this the return type of function is User and roles at end turns it into a collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191517/discussion-between-er-sho-and-jackal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the long discussion on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191517/discussion-between-er-sho-and-jackal) the below code works for OP.

```
private User Authenticate(LoginViewModel model) 
{ 
    using (HutLogisticaContext context = new HutLogisticaContext()) 
    { 
        return context.Users
                      .Include(u => u.Roles)
                      .Where(u => u.Id == 123)
                      .SingleOrDefault(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your user EF entity already has the roles association setup as a navigation collection property, i.e.

```
public class User
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
   ...
```

What you can do use tell EF to eager load this navigation when you retrieve your user:

```
return context.Users
  .Include(u => u.Roles)  // << i.e. Force EF to Join the UserRoles assocated with User
  .Where(...)
  .SingleOrDefault()
```

In the calling method, you can now access the `user.Roles`, or use your `user.Roles.Any()` logic to see whether a user has the role etc.

There's a couple of other things
 - Since user names seemingly should be unique in the System, `Contains` (mapped to SQL `IN`) seems the wrong tool here. I would do a direct comparison, especially if you have the default Case Insensitive collation on the `User.UserName` column.
 - SingleOrDefault also has an overload allowing for the same predicate as a `Where` filter, so you can simplify this to:

```
return context.Users
   .Include(u => u.Roles)
   .SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == model.Username);
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer, sorry i can't choose it right because someone gave me this solution on chat before this post

Comment: Out of interest, why did you say that you can't use `.Include` in the OP? Eager loading with `.Include` is a really powerful tool which allows you to precisely define the 'depth' ([can be deeply nested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092178)) - of table joins in SQL, and easily allows you to build up a entity and all it's relations in memory (e.g. like an AggregateRoot in DDD terminology).

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe i did a mistake when writting include, but when i tried it gave me an exception about not having navigation. Probably a syntax error, i'm not very experienced with EF yet