# Inverse property EF Core code first dosn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to display list of users with products of every user.

So I have this in my classes :

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Product = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public decimal Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("UserNavigation")]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public decimal UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [InverseProperty("Products")]
    public virtual User UserNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Here when I want to display list users I didn't found any product for any user count is zero for products collection but in my database I have data and notice that here the relationship between this two tables is one to many.

So what could be the problem here?

Comment: Is you EF setup to load as Eager or lazy?

Comment: Could you share the code where you're populating the models please

Comment: @pix Eager Loading

Comment: Change it to lazy or you need to include this proprty in your load. Can you please show use the code that you are using to load the data ?https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092178/777716

Comment: Edit your question, do not add the code in the comment.

Comment: i think that the problem is that i dosn't set my include properties in my method when i load data so i must set the UserNavigation  in my include properties