# Entity Framework Core not loading related data from reference table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

MY Model `M:M` relationship Reference to
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx

**Models**

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Created By:")]
    public AppUser AuthorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string metaTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; } 
    public bool ISFeatured { get; set; }
    public DateTime CretedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime ModifiyDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public IList<PostTag> PostTag { get; set; }
    public IList<PostCategory> PostCategory { get; set; }
    public IList<Images> Images { get; set; }

}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime CretedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime ModifiyDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public IList<PostTag> PostTag { get; set; }
    public IList<Images> Images { get; set; }


}

public class PostTag
{

    public int TagId { get; set; }
   
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

}
```

**DB context**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Comments)
        .WithOne(e => e.Post);

modelBuilder.Entity<PostCategory>().HasKey(p => new
{
    p.PostId,p.CategoryId
});

modelBuilder.Entity<PostCategory>()
    .HasOne(p => p.post).
    WithMany(p => p.PostCategory).
    HasForeignKey(p => p.PostId);

modelBuilder.Entity<PostCategory>().
    HasOne(p => p.Category).
    WithMany(p => p.PostCategory).
    HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);
```

On the controller, side fetching all posts, it is bringing all the posts but not getting any data from the related tables. Example Tags, Categories

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Post.ToListAsync());
}
```

[image]

Update Action

[image]

Tags reference is empty

[image]

Comment: try `_context.Post.Include(x => x.PostCategory)` and so on

Comment: EfCore uses eager loading as a default and you need to specify the loading depth using the.Include extension. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092178/314291

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ThenInclude to continue including further levels of related data.

```
 var posts = _context.Posts.Include(p => p.PostTag).ThenInclude(pt => pt.Tag).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

try `_context.Post.Include(x => x.PostCategory)` and so on.

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: I changed it still no data showing please check image 2

Comment: It means `PostCategory` does not have any item

Comment: but quick question can you check the next image it fetching tags id bu the reference is empty