# Issue with Entity Framework Core: .Include() and .AsNoTracking() not displaying expected related entities

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Since upgrading from .NET Framework to .NET Core, I've encountered an unexpected behavior in Entity Framework Core related to the use of `.Include()` and `.AsNoTracking()` methods.

Consider the following entities:

```
public class Entity1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Entity2Id { get; set; }
    public Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entity1> Entity1s { get; set; }
 }
```

When I execute the query

```
Context.Entity1s.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Entity2)
```

and then attempt to access `Entity2.Entity1s` on the result, only a single element (the parent) is displayed instead of the entire list.

However, removing `.AsNoTracking()` results in the expected behavior, displaying the complete list of Entity1 elements that are linked to Entity2.

I'm trying to understand why this discrepancy occurs and why it behaves differently in EF Core.

Comment: If you start by specifying the includes yourself then you must go that path all the way. It essentially declares the left joins that will happen. To after the first `.Include(x => x.Entity2)` you must followup with a `.ThenInclude(x => x.Entity1s)`. Hope this makes sense. Check this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities?rq=2

Comment: @cleftheris Either I misunderstood your point or that is factually incorrect. Also see the mention in the question - _"However, removing `.AsNoTracking()` results in the expected behavior"_.

Comment: Yes I see now that the third level is the same as the first level entity. I was quick to comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, use `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` instead of just `AsNoTracking`:

```cs
Context.Entity1s
   .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
   .Include(x => x.Entity2)
```

Which should result in the desired output (if all the needed entities where fetched in the query).

From the [Identity resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#identity-resolution) section of the docs:

> Since a tracking query uses the change tracker, EF Core does identity resolution in a tracking query. When materializing an entity, EF Core returns the same entity instance from the change tracker if it's already being tracked. If the result contains the same entity multiple times, the same instance is returned for each occurrence. No-tracking queries:
>
> - Don't use the change tracker and don't do identity resolution.
> - Return a new instance of the entity even when the same entity is contained in the result multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Guru's answer, When you specify `AsNoTracking()` EF populates entities based on only what comes back from the database, it will not go to the tracking cache to fill in references, and the returned entities will not work with lazy loading which would otherwise fill in non-included references if you have lazy loading enabled.

In the case where you want to load *all* entity1's then using `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` should be enough. However, if you put any kind of filter on which Entity1's you load initially then you should eager load those as well, as per cleftharis's comment, but also use `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` to ensure that the Entity2.Entity1 referencing back to the initial one you load point to the same reference:

```
var entities = Context.Entity1s
    .Where(x => /* some condition */)
    .Include(x => x.Entity2)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Entity1s)
    .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution();
```

The reason is that otherwise `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` will only populate the Entity1 references in the Entity2s based on which Entity1s were loaded. So if an entity2 had a reference to an entity 1 that wasn't returned in the root query's conditions, it won't be populated in the results.

Alternatively, If you instead use:

```
var entities = Context.Entity1s // with, or without a Where condition...
    .Include(x => x.Entity2)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Entity1s)
    .AsNoTracking();
```

... then the results will appear to work, but a big problem is that:

```
var first = entities.First();
var childsParent = first.Entity2.Entity1s.Single(x => x.Id == first.Id);
bool sameReference = object.ReferenceEquals(first, childsParent);
```

"sameReference" in this case would be `false`. While they contain the same row they would be different, separate instances of an entity class. Ensuring the references to the same row use the same instance is the primary purpose for using `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution`.