# Incorrect joining of tables in linq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-objects

I have these entities:

```
Account
-IdAccount: 1
-Money: 20
-IdInfo: 2

Navigation Property:  Info

Info
-IdInfo: 2
-Info: hi

Navigation Property: Account
```

When I do something like this using linq

```
var account = storeDB.Accounts.Include("Info").Single( a => a.IdInfo == 2 );
```

This will do a join with IdAccount=1 and IdInfo= 1, instead of 2. Does anybody know a different way I can do a query? I looked at select from bla bla, but I dont know how to put that in an object, since I created an Account.cs, and Info.cs like the ASP MVC3 tutorial of music.

I have a feeling it does some sort of natural join and that's why it associates both Ids with number 1.

I have been checking this for a lot of hours, and haven't been able to resolve this, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `.Where( a => a.IdInfo == 2).Single();`

Comment: This doesn't work...I don't understand, does it do a special natural join or something? Does it have to do with the fact that it is a one to one relation? And it does some sort of authomatic join? despite the fact that i specify different id values?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Linq-to-Sql, try:

```
using (var storeDB = new DataContext())
{
    var options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<Accounts>(a => a.Info);
    db.LoadOptions = options;

    var account = from a in storeDB.Accounts
                  where a.IdInfo == 2
                  select a;
}
```

This answer will provide som extra information: [How do you construct a LINQ to Entities query to load child objects directly, instead of calling a Reference property or Load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315966/how-do-you-construct-a-linq-to-entities-query-to-load-child-objects-directly-ins/315985#315985)