# Possible to return linked object with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, .net, linq, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I have two tables, Customers and Orders. 1 customer can have multiple orders. There is a link between the two tables.

Currently using Linq to SQL to get the data and display it. The database has grown and results were displaying pretty slow.

After some reading I added a Stored Procedure (Added the SP to the dbml file which returns ISingleResult so created a new method where i iterated through the SP data and added it to my Customers object list). I did this to speed up in obtaining and displaying the data. So far this worked well.

The problem is when I used to get order details by a customer, I used to write this

```
foreach (Customer c in Customer)
{

 foreach (Order o in c.Orders)
  {
    // other logic here
  }

}
```

Using the Stored Procedure method c.Orders was null so I added the relevant relation to the SP but Orders is always null - the only thing that has changed is the number of rows returned which is the same as the number of orders the customer has placed, however I cant iterate through the orders like I did prior to adding the SP?

Any thoughts on where ive gone wrong or what to do?

My Stored Procedure:

```
Select Customers.*, Orders.ID 
FROM            
Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.Ordersid = Orders.Ordersid
```

In code I have

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomers
{
    ISingleResult<StoredProcedureName> AllCustomers = myDC.StoreProcedureName;
    List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();

    foreach (var c in AllCustomers)
    {
       //Add each property from SP into List properties and return List
    }

//....
}
```

Comment: I assume that you have a virtual property `Orders` on your customer class? And you are joining on the Orders table in the stored procedure? The procedure won't do that by itself just because of the relational table.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the procedure and how you are calling it.

Comment: I've added the basic SQL and C# code to my original post. Thx

Comment: Can you include the mapping files and the LINQ query that you say was working?

Comment: By that all i meant was, i dragged a table to my dbml file which did everything else for me. I didnt have to write any code on this part but all i did was get the customers and iterated through the data (code above) which was added to my Customer object and returned as a list

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need to use the Include clause to your query to force the dbcontext to load the navigation property "Orders" for each Customer. See this post:

[How do you construct a LINQ to Entities query to load child objects directly, instead of calling a Reference property or Load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315966/how-do-you-construct-a-linq-to-entities-query-to-load-child-objects-directly-in)

Comment: I don't think LINQ to Entities was the problem.  It sounds like @Computer has LINQ working, but converting it to the stored procedure was not.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually selecting the Orders object, you're only grabbing the ID.

Try simplifying your Stored Procedure to:

```
Select * -- take everything
FROM            
Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.Ordersid = Orders.Ordersid
```

Comment: I did that and got the same result. My guess is that the GetCustomers also needs modifying so the list knows theres orders available for that customer? If so i was lost at this stage :-(